# Is there any thing wrong with my getting location approach?

Tags: android

I have to submit my mini project. I write a class to get the user location. I want to know if there is any technical problem in my approach or not. It works fine. I am Using a Handler to get the location continuously.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Activity {

LocationTracker lt;
TextView tv;
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable locationRunner = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (lt.canGetLocation()) {
            tv.setText(lt.getLatitude() + " " + lt.getLongitude());
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lt = new LocationTracker(this);
    Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "GPS: " + lt.isGPSEnabled() + "\nNetwork: "
                    + lt.isNetworkEnabled() + "\nCanGetLocation: "
                    + lt.canGetLocation(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    handler.postDelayed(locationRunner, 1000);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    handler.removeCallbacks(locationRunner);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**LocationTracker.java**

```
public class LocationTracker implements LocationListener {

private Context context;
private boolean isGPSEnabled;
private boolean isNetworkEnabled;
private boolean isTracking;
private Location location;
private LocationManager locationManager;

public LocationTracker(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    isGPSEnabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (!isNetworkEnabled && !isGPSEnabled) {
        isTracking = false;
    } else {
        isTracking = true;
    }

    if (isGPSEnabled) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    } else if (isNetworkEnabled) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

}

public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        return location.getLatitude();
    } else {
        return 0.00;
    }
}

public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        return location.getLongitude();
    } else
        return 0.00;
}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return isTracking;
}

public boolean isGPSEnabled() {
    return isGPSEnabled;
}

public boolean isNetworkEnabled() {
    return isNetworkEnabled;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    location = arg0;
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {

}

}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, As I see it, 2 things are wrong.

1. Don't check for availability to `requestLocationUpdates`.
2. Instead listen to DATA connection changes and `removeUpdates`, and `requestLocationUpdates`.

Sample code

//OnCreate

```
tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    tm.listen(new NetworkConnectionState(this.getApplicationContext()),
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE 
| PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION );
```

//Your listener

```
public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state, int networkType) {
        // We have changed protocols, for example we have gone from HSDPA to
        // GPRS
        // HSDPA is an example of a 3G connection
        // GPRS is an example of a 2G connection
        if (state == TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED) {
        }
        else {
        }
    }
```

Edit :
Dont forget to update your connection / disconnection on `onProviderDisabled` and `onProviderEnabled` in your LocationListeners

Comment: pardon sir but why i do not have to check availability ? and i am listening to requestLocationUpdates() . can you explain more. i did not get you :-)

Comment: you mean onDestroy() called and i stop listening for updateListener ? okay i got it

Comment: You are just checking for availability once, instead this network thing is very unstable, you need to know when network is available and when not. You want the system to send a event/callback for you to do something with it. Thats a better design.

Comment: Not only on onDestroy, but also on "DATA_CONNECTED" = false. Hope its clear.

Answer (score 0):

isTraking=false if gps and network are both disabled when app launch, it never change to true even user enable both gps or network during app running. You should use the logic in onProviderDisabled and onProviderEnabled methods.

Comment: Before i get the location i am checking a `boolean` variable which will be true only if one of the two providers is Enabled.
like **This**
`public void run() {
        if (lt.canGetLocation()) {
            tv.setText(lt.getLatitude() + " " + lt.getLongitude());
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
 }`
But yeah During my application running i can manipulate this flag either true or false according to situation

Comment: o Yeah. i got it @jason Yong. Thanks. Good For me :-)