# LocationManager providerDisabled()

Tags: android, android-location

I want to know if a Certain Provider is Disabled will the `LocationManager` stop listening to the location changes for that provider ? If not then how can i manually stop listening for updates for that provider. Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your location listeners will not stop until you call `myLocationManager.removeUpdates(myListener);`. Check my answer to a different question [here] to know what else you need to do for connection status updates[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702015/is-there-any-thing-wrong-with-my-getting-location-approach/14702108#14702108).

Comment: I know. But i Am saying that what if i am listening for two providers. if my `gps` is disabled then will `LocationManager` be stop listening for `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`? if no how can i stop listening for just one provider that is disabled.

Comment: Documentation of the `onProviderDisabled (String provider)` call is 
`provider the name of the location provider associated with this update.`. Hope this helps.

Comment: okay i got it.Thanks. Now i will toggle my flags on and off according to which provider is enabled and which is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

give this a whirl

```
 myLocationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
 myListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("LocationListener", "Logging Change");
    }

  }

myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            5000, 1, myListener);

myLocationManager.removeUpdates(myListener);
```